# Mapbox gl js bearing auto reset to zero

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox gl js default rotate behavior is following: when user stop rotating map with bearing value close to zero (+-5deg) then map will auto correct bearing value to zero. My question is: how to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map), the default is 7 degrees. You should be able to set it to zero (ie, no automatic snap) by doing this:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
   ...
   bearingSnap: 0
});
```